# Response in Dictionary has no definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, dictionary

im new in C# but i cant find clearly response for my problem. my code is:

```
myDict.Add("BTC",jsonResponse.BTC);
myDict.Add("LTC", jsonResponse.LTC);
myDict.Add("DASH", jsonResponse.DASH);
myDict.Add("ETH", jsonResponse.ETH);
```

Its using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;


namespace helloApp

{

public class Posts
{

    public string BTC { get; set; }
    public string DASH { get; set; }
    public string ETH { get; set; }
    public string LTC { get; set; }

}


}
```

I want to make it automaticly by:

```
foreach(string x in jsonResponse){
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

but i have an error:

> Error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Posts' because 'Posts' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' (CS1579) (helloApp)

- // I want to automaticly search in my dictionary.

Edited:

I want to generate myDict using items from public class Posts, fe:

Now im doing

```
myDict.Add("BTC",jsonResponse.BTC);
myDict.Add("LTC", jsonResponse.LTC);
myDict.Add("DASH", jsonResponse.DASH);
myDict.Add("ETH", jsonResponse.ETH);
```

I want to do foreach:

```
myDict.Add(string X,jsonResponse.X)
```

to make automaticly the same result like in myDict.Add("BTC" ... etc... )

Edit:

According to answer, thank you for help:

You have to make a dictionary variable:

```
            var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

then add elements to myDict:

```
foreach (var prop in jsonResponse.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!myDict.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                    myDict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(jsonResponse)?.ToString());
            }
```

and you can use it:

```
        foreach (var item in myDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "  " + item.Value);
        }
```

Because microsoft tutorials make it more difficulty than it is.

Comment: Well, Posts doesn't implement `IDictionary`, so you're not "searching in your dictionary". It doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, either, so you can't iterate through it.

Comment: Are you sure you're iterating the correct object? From what you describe it sounds as if you want to iterate myDict, not jsonResponse.

Comment: @John hmm in python it was easier. So i found instructions in microsoft page, but i still dont know how to implement IEnumerable.

Comment: @Shazi with Dict its no problem:

foreach(var reset in myDict){
                finalRow += reset.Key + ": " + reset.Value + "\n";
               
            }

but i want to specify to automaticly "myDict.add" items every time my method is running.

Comment: Rather than implementing IEnumerable, why not use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`? e.g. `Dictionary<string, Post>` (where `Post` contains a single value)?

Comment: @John please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use reflection by `GetProperties` method to get all properties then add them in the Dictionary.

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var prop in jsonResponse.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (!myDict.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
        myDict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(jsonResponse)?.ToString());
}
```

Or simple way you can use linq `ToDictionary` to make it.

```
var myDict1 = jsonResponse.GetType()
                        .GetProperties()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(jsonResponse)?.ToString());
```

if you want to get values and keys you need to iterator from the Dictionary because `foreach` implement [iterator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern), which object need to implement `IEnumerable` interface and that collection have behavior to iterator .

```
foreach (var item in myDict)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "  "+ item.Value);
```

Comment: its propably working, but System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String] 
cant simply encode it.

Comment: @Kamil What's your mean `cant simply encode it.` could you post more detail about it or show me your full code?

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var prop in jsonResponse.GetType().GetProperties()){
                if (!newDict.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                    newDict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(jsonResponse)?.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(newDict);
            }


gives me 

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
(...) a lot of times, not human readable keys and values

Comment: @Kamil I edit my answer you need to iterator from the `Dictionary` again.

Comment: or use   `Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + "  " + prop.GetValue(jsonResponse)?.ToString());`  instead of  `Console.WriteLine(newDict);`

Comment: because when you use `Console.WriteLine(newDict);` you will call  `Dictionary<string, string>` Tostring mehtod.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it working i will update my Q ;-)